# What causes UI hiccups when using C# BinaryFormatter.Deserialize?

Tags: c#, serialization, binary

I'm using a BinaryFormatter to serialize and deserialize a list of items into byte[] arrays, and I've noticed that for a significant number of elements in the list my UI will hang or have "hiccups".  When I say significant, I'm talking about 10K items (each with a collection of items of their own).

What is interesting is that the serialization and deserialization occurs on a separate thread, so I would not have thought UI interruptions would have occurred.  I was just curious if anyone has dealt with anything similar, and if there are any workarounds.

The code snippets below are from the stripped down sol'n that I'm testing with.  While I'm using the BinaryFormatter to read and write to disk here as well, the part I'm more interested in is what is in the SerializationHelper class (where it is being done in memory).

I also realize that the UI thread will be interrupted to post status updates, however those are negligible.  I'm noticing the UI hangs while BinaryFormatter.Deserialize is executing and nothing is being updated on the UI.

**DataReader**:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace SerializationTesting
{
  internal class DataReader : DataIOBase
  {
    #region Constants

    private const int MAX_STEPS = 2;

    #endregion

    #region Declarations

    private string _file;

    #endregion

    public DataReader(string file)
    {
      _file = file;
    }

    protected override void DoWork()
    {
      UpdateStatus(0, MAX_STEPS, "Reading from file...");

      byte[] serializedData = ReadFromDisk();

      UpdateStatus(1, MAX_STEPS, "Deserializing data...");

      if (serializedData == null) return;

      DeserializeData(serializedData);

      UpdateStatus(2, MAX_STEPS, "Finished!");
    }

    private byte[] ReadFromDisk()
    {
      byte[] serializedData = null;

      using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(_file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
        using (BufferedStream bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(stream))
        {
          BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
          serializedData = formatter.Deserialize(bufferedStream) as byte[];
        }
      }

      return serializedData;
    }

    private void DeserializeData(byte[] serializedData)
    {
      List<Data> dataList = SerializationHelper.Deserialize(serializedData, new List<Data>());

      dataList.Clear();
      dataList = null;
      serializedData = null;
    }
  }
}
```

**DataWriter**:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace SerializationTesting
{
  internal class DataWriter : DataIOBase
  {
    #region Declarations

    private string _file;
    private int _count;

    #endregion

    public DataWriter(string file, int count)
    {
      _file = file;
      _count = count;
    }

    protected override void DoWork()
    {
      int maxSteps = _count + 2;

      UpdateStatus(0, maxSteps, "Creating data...");

      List<Data> dataList = CreateData(maxSteps);

      UpdateStatus(_count, maxSteps, "Serializing data...");

      byte[] serializedData = SerializationHelper.Serialize(dataList, null);

      UpdateStatus(_count + 1, maxSteps, "Writing to file...");

      WriteToDisk(serializedData, maxSteps);

      serializedData = null;
      dataList.Clear();
      dataList = null;

      UpdateStatus(maxSteps, maxSteps, "Finished!");
    }

    private List<Data> CreateData(int maxSteps)
    {
      List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>();

      for (int i = 0; i < _count; i++)
      {
        UpdateStatus(i, maxSteps, string.Format("Creating item {0}...", i + 1));

        Data data = new Data();
        dataList.Add(data);
      }

      return dataList;
    }

    private void WriteToDisk(byte[] serializedData, int maxSteps)
    {
      using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(_file, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
      {
        using (BufferedStream bufferedStream = new BufferedStream(stream))
        {
          BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
          formatter.Serialize(bufferedStream, serializedData);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**DataIOBase**:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

namespace SerializationTesting
{
  internal abstract class DataIOBase
  {
    #region Declarations

    private Thread _thread;

    #endregion

    #region Events

    public event UpdateStatusHandler OnStatusChange;
    public event ProcessCompleteHandler OnComplete;

    #endregion

    public void Start()
    {
      KillThread();

      _thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadBody));
      _thread.Start();
    }

    private void KillThread()
    {
      if (_thread == null) return;
      if (!_thread.IsAlive) return;

      try
      {
        _thread.Abort();
      }
      catch { }
    }

    private void ThreadBody()
    {
      Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
      sw.Start();

      try
      {
        DoWork();
      }
      catch { }
      finally
      {
        sw.Stop();

        if (OnComplete != null)
        {
          OnComplete(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
      }
    }

    protected abstract void DoWork();

    protected void UpdateStatus(int curr, int max, string status)
    {
      if (OnStatusChange == null) return;
      OnStatusChange(curr, max, status);
    }
  }
}
```

**Data**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace SerializationTesting
{
  [Serializable]
  public class Data : ISerializable
  {
    #region Static Members

    private static readonly int COLLECTION_SIZE_MIN = 1;
    private static readonly int COLLECTION_SIZE_MAX = 20;

    private static Random _rand = null;
    private static Random Rand
    {
      get
      {
        if (_rand == null)
        {
          _rand = new Random();
        }

        return _rand;
      }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Instance Properties

    public string Name1 { get; set; }
    public string Name2 { get; set; }
    public string Name3 { get; set; }
    public string Name4 { get; set; }
    public string Name5 { get; set; }
    public int Num1 { get; set; }
    public int Num2 { get; set; }
    public int Num3 { get; set; }
    public int Num4 { get; set; }
    public int Num5 { get; set; }
    public bool Bool1 { get; set; }
    public bool Bool2 { get; set; }
    public bool Bool3 { get; set; }
    public bool Bool4 { get; set; }
    public bool Bool5 { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<int, Data> Collection { get; set; }

    #endregion

    public Data(bool createCollection = true)
    {
      Init(createCollection);
    }

    #region Init

    private void Init(bool createCollection)
    {
      try
      {
        Name1 = CreateString();
        Name2 = CreateString();
        Name3 = CreateString();
        Name4 = CreateString();
        Name5 = CreateString();
        Num1 = CreateInt();
        Num2 = CreateInt();
        Num3 = CreateInt();
        Num4 = CreateInt();
        Num5 = CreateInt();
        Bool1 = CreateBool();
        Bool2 = CreateBool();
        Bool3 = CreateBool();
        Bool4 = CreateBool();
        Bool5 = CreateBool();
        CreateCollection(createCollection);
      }
      catch { }
    }

    private string CreateString()
    {
      int length = Rand.Next(1, 31);
      char[] value = new char[length];

      for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
      {
        int charValue = Rand.Next(48, 91);
        value[i] = (char)i;
      }

      return new string(value);
    }

    private int CreateInt()
    {
      return Rand.Next(1, 11);
    }

    private bool CreateBool()
    {
      int value = Rand.Next(0, 2);

      return value == 0 ? false : true;
    }

    private void CreateCollection(bool populateCollection)
    {
      Collection = new Dictionary<int, Data>();

      if (!populateCollection) return;

      int count = Rand.Next(COLLECTION_SIZE_MIN, COLLECTION_SIZE_MAX + 1);

      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
      {
        Data data = new Data(false);
        Collection.Add(i, data);
      }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Serialization

    public Data(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
      SerializationHelper sh = new SerializationHelper(info);

      Name1 = sh.GetItem("Name1", string.Empty);
      Name2 = sh.GetItem("Name2", string.Empty);
      Name3 = sh.GetItem("Name3", string.Empty);
      Name4 = sh.GetItem("Name4", string.Empty);
      Name5 = sh.GetItem("Name5", string.Empty);
      Num1 = sh.GetItem("Num1", -1);
      Num2 = sh.GetItem("Num2", -1);
      Num3 = sh.GetItem("Num3", -1);
      Num4 = sh.GetItem("Num4", -1);
      Num5 = sh.GetItem("Num5", -1);
      Bool1 = sh.GetItem("Bool1", false);
      Bool2 = sh.GetItem("Bool2", false);
      Bool3 = sh.GetItem("Bool3", false);
      Bool4 = sh.GetItem("Bool4", false);
      Bool5 = sh.GetItem("Bool5", false);
      Collection = sh.GetItem("Collection", new Dictionary<int, Data>());
    }

    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, SerializationFormatter = true)]
    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
      info.AddValue("Name1", Name1);
      info.AddValue("Name2", Name2);
      info.AddValue("Name3", Name3);
      info.AddValue("Name4", Name4);
      info.AddValue("Name5", Name5);
      info.AddValue("Num1", Num1);
      info.AddValue("Num2", Num2);
      info.AddValue("Num3", Num3);
      info.AddValue("Num4", Num4);
      info.AddValue("Num5", Num5);
      info.AddValue("Bool1", Bool1);
      info.AddValue("Bool2", Bool2);
      info.AddValue("Bool3", Bool3);
      info.AddValue("Bool4", Bool4);
      info.AddValue("Bool5", Bool5);
      info.AddValue("Collection", Collection);
    }

    #endregion
  }
}
```

**SerializationHelper**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

namespace SerializationTesting
{
  public class SerializationHelper
  {
    #region Declarations

    private SerializationInfo _serializationInfo;

    #endregion

    public SerializationHelper(SerializationInfo serializationInfo)
    {
      _serializationInfo = serializationInfo;
    }

    #region Get Item

    public T GetItem<T>(string item, T defaultValue)
    {
      try
      {
        object value = _serializationInfo.GetValue(item, typeof(T));
        return (T)value;
      }
      catch
      {
        return defaultValue;
      }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Binary Serialization

    public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] serializedObject, T defaultValue, SerializationBinder binder = null)
    {
      if (serializedObject == null) return defaultValue;

      try
      {
        object deserializedObject;
        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        if (binder != null)
        {
          binaryFormatter.Binder = binder;
        }

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(serializedObject))
       {
          stream.Seek(0, 0);

          deserializedObject = binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }

        if (!(deserializedObject is T))
        {
          return defaultValue;
        }

        return (T)deserializedObject;
      }
      catch
      {
        return defaultValue;
      }
    }

    public static byte[] Serialize(object o, byte[] defaultValue, SerializationBinder binder = null)
    {
      if (o == null) return null;

      try
      {
        byte[] serializedObject;
        BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        if (binder != null)
        {
          binaryFormatter.Binder = binder;
        }

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
          binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, o);
          serializedObject = stream.ToArray();
        }

        return serializedObject;
      }
      catch
      {
        return defaultValue;
      }
    }

    #endregion
  }
}
```

Comment: Garbage collection pauses can trivially explain this.  Use a decent profiler.

Comment: GC does seem to be a factor.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, as of Nov 2020, MS recommends [not using using BinaryFormatter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/binaryformatter-serialization-obsolete) in your code.

Instead, consider using JsonSerializer or XmlSerializer. For more information, see [BinaryFormatter security guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide).